# Writing not importing into Careers site

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Actions:

1. On careers.stackoverflow.com editing resume
2. Clicked "Add Writing"
3. Inserted "http://blog.chomperstomp.com/git-it-now/" into the text box
4. Clicked "get article"

Expected Result:

Something to happen (Not sure what... This is my first time adding writing)

Actual Result:

Nothing happened. The page just sat there, the button disabled as if it were working. No error message, nothing.

I'm in Chrome, so I hit Ctrl+Shift+J and looked at the console. It displayed the following error:

GET http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/import/writing/9101 500 (InternalServerError)

Comment: I've got the same issue. Can't add my articles from channel9 coding4fun blog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that's an odd one. I took a look at the error logs and there is an invalid XML character in that page somewhere.

I've worked around it, give it another try?